# Unable to update new column values in rows which were derived from existing column having multiple values separeted by ','?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Original dataframe

[image: DF1 - original dataframe]

Converted Dataframe using stack and split:

[image: Converted Dataframe using stack and split]

Adding new column to a converted dataframe:

[image: Adding new column to a converted dataframe]

What i am trying to is add a new column using np.select(condition, values) but it not updating the two addition rows derived from H1 its returning with 0 or NAN. Can someone please help me here ?

Please note i have already done the reset index but still its not helping.

Comment: you should provide 1- your data as text, 2- explanation on how you perform the existing steps, 3- the logic to get the new column

Comment: Hi Mozway, i added new rows using df = df.drop('H!', axis=1).join(df['H1'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('H1'))   and after that i am using list of conditions and values. For eg: conditions = [
    (Temp['H1']== 'NY' ),
    (Temp['State']== 'CT' )]    Values = ['230000','4400000'] and then use assign new column to df using Temp['H3'] = np.select(conditions,values)

Comment: please edit the question

Comment: why don't you use df['H3'] = df.ID *2 for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think using numpy in this situation is kind of unnecessary.
you can use something like the following code:

```
df[df.State == 'CT']['H3'] = 4400000
```

Comment: so one more thing to add in here all those rows that are being derived from columns with multi values are not being manipulated or updated i just get blanks or zero if i am trying to add in any new column

Comment: Did you try this solution? What was the result? Are you sure that you are using the correct data types?